# No key.store and key.alias properties found in build.properties

Tags: java, android, ant, build-process

I am using `ant-release` to do a 1-step build of my Android app.

My build.properties looks like this:

```
application.package=xxxxx
key.store=sonr
key.alias=sonr labs
key.store.password=xxxx
key.alias.password=xxxx
```

When I run ant-release everything is fine except for application signing. I get the error:

```
-release-prompt-for-password:

-release-nosign:
     [echo] No key.store and key.alias properties found in build.properties.
     [echo] Please sign /Users/syalam/Documents/git/joeborn-sonr/sonr/bin/SONR-release-unsigned.apk manually
     [echo] and run zipalign from the Android SDK tools.
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/syalam/Documents/git/joeborn-sonr/sonr/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/syalam/Documents/git/joeborn-sonr/sonr/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/syalam/Documents/git/joeborn-sonr/sonr/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /Users/syalam/Documents/git/joeborn-sonr/sonr/bin/build.prop
```

How can I resolve this?

PS. I followed this tutorial for getting my build process down http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html

Comment: You're on a Mac it looks like. Have you used `ant-release` and that keystore successfully before? Have you moved any files around...could be a permission issue?

Comment: Yes, I'm on a Mac. This is my first time trying ant-release. I can export fine using the Eclipse GUI.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I had this problem too recently, I think that that tutorial is out of date...

The `key.alias` etc directives need to be in a file named **ant.properties**. There's no file called build.properties any more.

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction! I'm getting the error `[signjar] jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: /Users/syalam/Documents/git/joeborn-sonr/sonr/sonr (No such file or directory)` not sure why the extra `/sonr` directory is showing up, because it doesn't exist on my filepath, where can I change this?

Comment: I don't know what 'sonr' is... are you sure this is a result of 'ant release' and not some unrelated process?  What version of Ant & JDK are you using?

Comment: ant release is the only command I'm running. Is there a place where I can specify the path for jarsigner to not include this extra /sonr directory? sonr is the name of my application

Comment: I believe I have resolved it. They keystore needs to be in the same directory as build.xml, I had it in another folder

Comment: ant.properties worked for me with the keystore set to a full path in another directory.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. Bizarre that the very latest download of Eclipse & Android SDK clearly says 'No key.store and key.alias properties found in build.properties' when you run ant release..

Answer (score 4):

Ultimate answer of any this kind of question is in android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml

Document is at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html

Comment: the link does not work anymore. please revise it and provide a new link. This is precisely why we had to paste the most important parts of the links we share on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

regarding 'Sheehan Alam' issue that follows file name fix

> [signjar] jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: ...

You probably have key.store set to a value with a full path.

Make sure that you are using '/' and not '\'.

Answer (score 0):

Is `keystore` the name of your keystore file? From the tutorial:

> Where keystore is the name of your keystore file and change the value
>   of key.alias to your keystore's alias. Now when you run ant release,
>   you will be prompted for your passwords, and the build will
>   automatically sign and zipalign your package.

In your example above, you're using the same value for both `key.store` and `key.alias`.

---

The only other potential discrepancy I can see is that `-release-nosign:` is referencing **build.properties** when looking for `key.store` and `key.alias`, but referencing **build.props** later on.

I'm not an Andriod developer, so the best I can do is be a second pair of eyes; sorry.

Comment: I've updated my question to correctly reflect what the values are. I have x'd out the password for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a project that you'd like to add the Ant build script to, then there is an easy command line tool you can use. Open up a command prompt and navigate to the base directory of your project. From there, use the command:

```
android update project --path .
```

Answer (score 0):

add "<"property file="build.properties" /">" 
in your build.xml at the project folder.